# TeamCity 7.0 Dependency and versions

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have decided to follow "best practice" and only build my artifacts once and share them amongst my various builds. So I have created a master build that just builds the correct artifacts and then have the other builds have an artifact dependency to import the pre-built assemblies and .exe.

Unfortunately I have come across a bit of a problem with this. The builds with the artifact dependencies don't have the same version as the master build. So the master build version might be 2.2.11.6787 but the build that runs the tests has a version number of 2.2.111.6787 even though it is using the artifacts that have a version of 2.2.11.6787. The same applies to the nightly build that runs the full test suite.

Is there any way that the builds that have the artifact dependency could inherit the version information from the master build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep build numbers in sync between builds connected by an artifact dependencies using [Dependencies Properties](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties)
Just set build number pattern for test or nightly build to %dep.<bt_id>.build.number% where <bt_id> is the ID of your master build configuration